# Using a KML file to display thumbnail & full size pictures in My Maps

Tags: kml, mymaps

I'm afraid my **original post was not very clear**, so I've rewritten my question.

My basic question is how to modify a KML file to best display (in Google My Maps) two or more photos taken at a particular location. No matter what I do to the KML file (see below), when I click on a marker  I always end up with only the first picture being displayed TWICE as shown in this example:

[Result of clicking on a place marker with 2 pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykHtD.png)

Below is a snippet of my KML code. Please note that <img src... points to the full-sized version of the picture.

```
# Marker(s) [1, 2]

<Placemark>
  <name>Markers 1,2</name>
  <styleUrl>#Pic2</styleUrl>
  <description>
    <![CDATA[
        <table>
        <tr>
          <td>[1] This Monarch butterfly found Bob H. at the beginning of the hike and stayed around quite awhile!</td>
          <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=open&id=16a_438A1OCihb1SnYUPm0t9O3WDEdt6u">
        </tr>
        <tr>  
          <td>[2] Denny L. along with Sarah (and "Cooper") also seem ready to start.</td>
          <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=open&id=1KMGYeJDgqBDJwgkwYju6vlA8--XehACQ">
        </tr>
        </table>
    ]]>
  </description>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>-82.7915648,35.2841368</coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>
```

If I click on EITHER of the pictures in the example I get the full-sized version of that picture. Then, using the ">" and "<" that are displayed next to that full-sized picture I can move to the other pictures taken at that location. This isn't TERRIBLE, but I'd really like to initially see thumbnails of all the pictures taken at a particular location. Clicking on a thumbnail should then bring up the full-sized version. (Also, I don't really want 2 copies of the first picture!)

No matter what I do - including adding an  line pointing to the thumbnail - I get exactly the same result when clicking on a marker.

I'm not sure if it is possible to do what I'd like, but any suggestions/thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Wayne

Comment: The posted HTML is not valid (missing a closing ">" for the first `<img>` tag), and it probably should have `<table>` tags.  What do you mean by "have the full size version pop up"?  Pop up in a new window?

Comment: You seem to be correct about the closing ">" on the <img> tag, but interestingly I have hundreds of KML files with that problem and everything works fine without any error messages... Perhaps My Maps overlooks such things? And yes, it would be nice if the full-sized version of the image came up in a new window when the thumbnail was clicked. Alternatively, clicking on text such as "Click here for full-sized image" to bring up the image would be fine.

Comment: My original image showing the result of clicking on a Marker was only correct when I was viewing the website. For other users, the pictures and links to the full sized pictures appear in a panel to the left of the map. This provides more space for the descriptions & links to each full-sized picture, but only one truncated thumbnail is shown at the top of the panel and one truncated thumbnail at the bottom. It seems there should be a more attractive way of showing the thumbnails and providing access to the full-sized images...

Comment: Please take a look at my original posting. I've completely rewritten the question completely to clarify my problem...